# F = ma and Speed of Light

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, special-relativity, forces, speed-of-light, acceleration

Hello :) I'm a 12th grade student and I often ask myself, the speed of light is **299 792 458 m / s**
An object with a mass **m** and a constant force **F** has a acceleration **a = F/m**, for exemple, an object A with a **mass m = 10kg gets a constant acceleration F = 100N**, it has an acceleration **a = 100/10 = 10 m/s²**, so why does the object A doesn't go from **0m/s to an infinite value**, indeed:

**299 792 458 / 10 = 299 792 45,8 s**
so why with more than **299 792 45,8 s** the Object velocity doesn't go further?
Does it mean that the formula **F = ma** is not true for big value ? :o

Comment: That is correct.  $F=ma$ is only approximately correct for speeds much less than the speed of light.  Look up "special relativity".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$F=ma$ calculation taking relativity into account?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/128136) Found in the "related" column.

Answer (score 2):

You're right, $F=ma$ isn't true for big velocity. When you're moving at high speed, you must use relativistic formulas, involving the gamma factor $\gamma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$, in this case $\vec{F}=\frac{dP}{dt}$, where $P$ is the relativistic momentum, defined as $p(v)=\gamma mv$  (edited)

Comment: $\vec F=\gamma m \vec a$ is not the correct relativistic correction for Newton's second law.

Comment: I would like to point to https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/64159/mass-in-special-relativity and the @Alpha Centauri answer

Comment: In particular, in 1-D motion (like what OP is describing), $F=\gamma^3 ma$.